# prepareForSegue after didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

Can we make a rank like prepareForSegue after didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

My NSLog sends a good sentence, this NSLog is that I want (in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but assign AFTER to my NSLog in prepareForSegue) I would like the NSLog in prepareForSegue sends the same sentence that didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.cellSelected = cell.textLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"la : %@", self.cellSelected);
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhotoView"]) {
        NSLog(@"ou %@", self.cellSelected);

        PhotoViewController *viewController = (PhotoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.cellSelected = self.cellSelected;

    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch the problem is I can't pass the value of "cell.textLabel.text;" of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath because that pass to cellSelected AFTER changing view... :/

Comment: I get it, the problem is that `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called before `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a segue that originates from a UITableViewCell the `sender` parameter will actually contain the UITableViewCell that was selected. So you could just use the sender parameter to get the data you need.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhotoView"]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;

        PhotoViewController *viewController = (PhotoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.cellSelected = cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can ! You need just to fix some things

Here is an example i used

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"friends2" sender:self];



}



- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"friends2"]) {

NSString * object = nil;
   NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = nil;

if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
    indexPath2 = [[ self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView]indexPathForSelectedRow];
    object = self.results[indexPath2.row];
    NSLog(@"is active : %@", object.self);
} else
{
    indexPath2 = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    object = sortedArray.self[indexPath2.row];
     NSLog(@"is not active : %@", object.self);
}
```

with didSelect.. i just made the segue, and with performSegue you do what you want to do

Comment: That's right ! But now I have another problem :
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.